# How to upload an APK to Play Store without publishing to any tracks using fastlane

Tags: android, google-play, apk, fastlane-supply

I believe I have an unconventional requirement: using fastlane, I need to be able to upload APKs to Play Store so they are available in the Library when doing a new release, and in App Bundle Explorer, but I don't want them to be published to any track. I'm wondering if anyone else tried that and succeeded.

Reading Supply's documentation and trying to reverse engineer its code, I was unable to find a way to achieve that.